# Reloading a Web page according to a condition

Tags: html, jsp

I'm a beginner in web development and I'm making a project in JSP. According to tutorialspoint, JSP is only able to auto reload a web page based on predefined x number of seconds. I want to reload the web page everytime I receive a high priority SIP MESSAGE from the servlet context, shown in the code below:

```
<%@ page import="java.io.*,java.util.*" %>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>High priority alert has been received !!!</title>
</head>
 <body>
  <p>
    <%
       if (MESSAGEHighPrio == null) {
           out.println("No high priority alerts have been received yet.");
           String MESSAGELowPrio = (String)this.getServletContext().getAttribute("MESSAGEFromLowPrioSIPServlet");

       }

       else{
           // RELOAD THE PAGE HERE !!!!
           out.println("<h1>High priority alert has been received !!!</h1>");
           out.println("Address: " + MESSAGEHighPrio + "\n");
       }
      %>
</p>
```

Comment: What is your problem ? Please be more clear

Comment: I want to update the web page everytime the else statement occurs

Comment: You are trying to say that it is not getting inside your `if` block . Am i correct ?

Comment: Yes exactly. Only the else block should update the web page.

Comment: Could get your question clearly still. can you please [join here](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/50387/sankrish)